# How to display long sentences as two lines in nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm using Nextjs to code a website, I want my longer text to be displayed as 2 lines

For example this

```
This is an example
```

would be like this instead

```
This is
an example
```

After some researching I found something, I then added this to my `styles.js` file but didn't work. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it

```
exampleClass: {
    fontSize: 13,
    width: '81px',
    display: 'webkit-box',
    WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
    WebkitLineClamp: 2,
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
```

It's been bugging me for awhile now, so any helps would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

1. You could add a `<br/>` tag where you want to get the break. i.e `This is an <br/> example`
2. You could wrap the content in a container with a width and set a `word-break` in CSS , example

`<div class="container"> This is an example </div>`

where the corresponding CSS could set the width and wrap

In your CSS

`.container { width: 100px;  word-break:break-all; /* Assuming 100px is what it takes and introduces a line break for you */ }`

Comment: `word-break: all` will create line breaks even mid-word. This doesn't seem related to the question or the desired result.